# Read multiple files async

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, file, io

I want to read multiple files simultaneously and apply the same function on data.

This code works correctly, but can someone please suggest any better way of writing this?

```
function fileread(path,stats,callback){
   var buffer = new Buffer(stats.size);
   fs.readFile(path, buffer, function(err, data){
      if(err){
         throw err;
      }

      callback(null, data);
   });
}

function testAsync() {
    var files = ['Statistics_Schema.json','seriesData'];
    async.map(files, fs.stat, function(err, stats){
       var i=0;
       async.map(files, function(path, callback){
          fileread(path, stats[i++], callback);
          },function(err, data){
                for(var j=0; j < data.length; j++){
                 console.log(data[j].toString());
                }
           });
    });
}
```

Comment: Use `promise` pattern. Recommend to read: http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-callback-hell-promises-generators/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can shorten it to just

```
function testAsync() {
    var files = ['Statistics_Schema.json', 'seriesData'];
    async.map(files, fs.readFile, function (err, data) {
        for(var i = 0, l = data.length ; i < l ; i++) {
            console.log( data[i].toString() );
        }
    });
}
```

Right now, you're first calling `fs.stat` on each file, only so you can create a buffer in your `fileread` method.

But `fs.readFile` *does not take a buffer argument*. It takes [an options object](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) (and there's no buffer option).

The `Buffer` object you're passing is an object, though, so Node doesn't complain. It just doesn't find any relevant `fileRead` options in that object either, so it's basically ignored.

So you don't need the buffer, which means you don't need `fs.stat`, which means you can skip almost all of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not using `fs.readFile`? I just tested this code:

```
var async = require('async'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    files = ['file1.json', 'file2.json'];

async.map(files, fs.readFile, function(err, files) {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    files.forEach(console.log);
});
```

If you wanna be able to read the file contents then replace the last line with

```
files.forEach(function(file) {
    console.log(file.toString());
});
```

Comment: He is using `fs.readFile` in `fileread` with a buffering option.

Comment: Hi @konjin - I thought that with both codes he would achieve the same results, then I googled about the difference in passing a buffer to `readFile`and could find nothing on the docs. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Interesting, it seems you are correct, passing `buffer` to `readFile` does not make any sense.

Comment: Also, see this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/59783/14625

Comment: At the time I answered @Flambino's answer wasn't visible to me, I believe its due to the migration from SO. Pretty much the same answer.